# A question about an explanation of the image of an immersion f:X$\to$Y need not to be a submanifold of Y

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

The explanation is:
From the Local Immersion Theorem,it is evident that f maps any sufficiently small NBHD W of an arbitrary point x diffeomorphically onto its image f(W) in Y. So every point in the image of f does sit within a parametrizable subset of f(X). Isn't this the definition of a manifold? No. For f(X) to be a manifold, points must have parametrizable NBHD, but subsets f(W) need not be open in Y.

I am confused about the last sentence. I don't think we can judge simply by f(W) maybe not open. Because if f(W) contains an open set containing f(x), then it also works.

Am I right?

Another question confuses me is:
As f maps any sufficiently small NBHD W of an arbitrary point x diffeomorphically onto its image f(W) in Y, and diffeomorphism implies homoemorphism so implies open map.In this sense, f can map an open map in W, containing x to an open map in f(W) containing f(x). And this image is a parametrizable open set containing f(x), thus we can get f(X) is a manifold. I know the result I get here is wrong, could you tell me where I went wrong? Thank you!

Comment: See if my updated answer helps better.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are helpful, and could you also have a look on my second question. Thank you again.

Comment: That addresses your updated question as well: the concept of homeomorphism depends on the topology you are using. Your map $f$ is a homeomorphism onto $f(W)$ with respect to the topology induced by $f$, but not necessarily with respect to the topology on $f(W)$ as a subspace of $Y$.

Comment: @GFR Thank you, I am still a little confused, please let me think about it for a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

Open sets in $f(X)$ need not to be open in $Y$. In other words the topology of $f(X)$ inherited from $X$ via the injective immersion $f$, which is $U$ open in $f(X)$ if it is the image of an open set in $X$, and the topology of $f(X)$ as a subspace of $Y$, that is $U$ open in $f(X)$ if $U$ is the intersection of an open set of $Y$ and $f(X)$, are generally different. When they are equal the immersion is called an embedding.

EDIT
I see you are using Guillemin, Pollack, while a lovely little book full of intuition, I found it a bit hard to pick up the technology of differential geometry from it because of its informal style. Anyway, try and think of the eight example realised as an injective immersion on page 16, figure 1.9. A neighbourhood of 0 on $\mathbb{R}$ is mapped to a little segment on the eight figure. An open set for the eight figure as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ would be a little open cross. Try and see this from the description of the two topologies I gave above. In fact the eight figure as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not even a manifold.

Comment: For my first question, do you think f(W) has to be open in Y? I don't think so, I think sometimes we can find a subset containing f(x), which is open in Y

Comment: I think about my second question, I do make mistake which lies in that I think f maps open map from W to f(W), but it is necessary to be  open in Y, right?